# Zend framework URLs not working in local environment

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I finally got a basic framework set up and working, however now when I wish to add an action in the 'IndexController.php', it doesn't seem to be working.

I used the following terminal command to add an "about" action:

```
zf create action about index
```

It appears that worked, as I opened 'IndexController.php' back up and the new action function is there. And a corresponding 'about.phtml' file was created in 'views/scripts/index', alongside 'index.phtml' that was already there.

When I access the index at

```
http://localhost3:8888/
```

the page opens properly.

However if I now try to access the about page at

```
http://localhost3:8888/index/about
```

I get a "404 not found" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a view script corresponding to the about Action?

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite turned on? Check that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in your httpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a `mod_rewrite` problem.

Try `http://localhost3:8888/index.php/index/about`. If it works, then it definitely means that `mod_rewrite` wasn't correctly set up.